# ExtJS Add panel above already added panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel, addition

I have a panel with a vbox layout. I want to add a panel to it ABOVE a panel that was declared in the items field when the container panel was created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `Panel.insert(index, component)`. According to Ext-JS 3.4 documentation, it will insert a component at the specified index of the Panel's `items` array.